# Numbers Bubble Chart Bubble Radius

Tags: macos, numbers

I can't figure out how to change the radii of the bubbles in a bubble chart in Numbers. I tried taking the original data and dividing it by 10, or 100, and redirecting the `Size:` data to the new column, but the bubble size hasn't changed.

I'm finding Numbers to be frustratingly counterintuitive, and haven't found any mention of this yet on the [Numbers Help Page](https://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/4.2/).

Edit: I used a circle detecting script to find the eclipse in the frames of a video, then I plotted the `x,y` coordinates of each circle, and wanted to use the radius of the found circles for the size of the bubbles—there probably isn't enough variation to matter, but obviously being so large is useless.

[image]

Comment: Without revealing your actual data, do you have an example of what you mean to do?  How is your data structured?

Comment: You can make your bubbles smaller by adding another data value (i.e. a set of x, y, and size values) in which your x and y values are blank and your size value is larger than all other size values.
Source: [Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7354237)

Comment: Thanks @user2421192! I just added one extra line at the top, empty coordinates, but a radius of 1000 (or 5000), and it adjusted the rest accordingly. (Somewhat annoying they don't have a way to just do that though.)

Answer (score 2):

@user2421192's comment had the solution: apparently the bubbles are automatically scaled proportionally to the range of the *radius* data. So by adding a new `row` at the top of my data, without *x* or *y* data, but just a *r* radius value, rescaled the rest of the data.

Since the radii I have don't vary by much, I decided to modify them with a formula, taking the `exp` of the original radius `r` divided by ten (`exp(r/10)`), and then setting my "scale" radius to `50 * max(radius)` (of the rest of the column), which gives some variation in the bubbles that makes it a little clearer whether they're bigger or smaller than the rest.[image: Usefully scaled bubble radii]